# Find out how many fingers used in pan gesture--UIPanGestureRecogniser

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, multi-touch

I was wondering if there was a way to get the number of fingers that the user is panning with. I know that `UIPanGestureRecogniser` has the `minimumNumberOfTouches` and the `maximumNumberOfTouches`, but that is not what I want. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the `numberOfTouches` property. Have a look at the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/numberOfTouches).